# Android: Realm + Retrofit 2 + Gson

Tags: java, android, gson, realm, retrofit

I have a problem when using *Retrofit* + *Gson* and *Realm*. I know that there is an issue with the combination of these 3 libraries. Some answers suggest that setting an `ExclusionStrategy` for *Gson* can solve this issue, and I tried it but it didn't work.

My code looks like:

```
public class ObjectList {
    public List<AnotherObject> anotherObject;
 }

public class AnotherObject extends RealmObject {
    private String propA;
    public void setPropA(String propA){
       this.setPropA = propA
    }
    public String getPropA(){
       return propA
    }
}

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new  ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false;
        }
    }).create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    ObjectAPI objectAPI = retrofit.create(ObjectAPI.class);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ObjectList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ObjectList> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            objectList = response.body().anotherObject;
            onRefreshComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connection to server failed, please check your connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

With the current code, I'm still getting the memory leak. Is there any suggestion for this code?

My json structure looks like:

```
{"anotherObject":[{"propA": "someValue"}]}
```

Comment: It is unclear what problem you are experiencing? What memory leak?

Comment: Hwo do you get `response.body().anotherObject;` ? You should be using `response.body().get(0..);` ?

Comment: Thank you all, now the problem is gone, i just add the exclusionstrategy to all of my gson instance.

Comment: @cana would be good if you clarify in details what was the problem (where was memory leak, how it happens) and how exactly you solved it, so others who land on this page can benefit as well. Otherwise whole Stackoverflow is losing point and with time it will get bloated with half asked, half answered posts

Comment: hi @Ewoks thanks for response..
currently i'm not working with android anymore..

Comment: @cana please don't leave questions in this state anymore. When other users land here they just waste time because of vague problem description and comments like "I just solved it, it doesn't matter anymore"

Comment: @cana could you please provide your answer? It's kinda unfair to the other users on stackoverlofw. It's about getting help and helping.

Answer (score 15):

> Why writing all these custom serializers when you can make *Gson* and
> *Realm* work together with just **ONE LINE OF CODE**?

## TL;DR.

You can simply solve this by passing unmanaged `RealmObjects` to your *Retrofit* calls.

```
MyModel model = realm.where(MyModel.class).findFirst();
MyModel unmanagedModel = realm.copyFromRealm(model);
// then pass unmanagedModel to your retrofit calls
```

If you don't want to go through all this answer, then skip to the **"Recommended solutions"** section posted down below.

## Long talk (verbose answer)

This has nothing to do with *Retrofit*. If you have set *Gson* to be the data converter to your current *Retrofit* instance, then you can be sure that it's *Gson* who's failing.

Suppose we have this Model:

```
public class Model extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
    boolean happy;

    public Model() {/* Required by both Realm and Gson*/}

    public Model(long id, boolean happy) {
        this.id = id;
        this.happy = happy;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isHappy() {
        return happy;
    }
}
```

For this code, we'll have no issue:

```
Model unmanagedModel = new Model(5, true); // unmanagedModel
new Gson().toJson(unmanagedModel);   // {id : 5, happy : true}
```

But for this one:

```
Realm realm = /*...*/;
Model managedModel = realm.copyToRealm(unmanagedModel);
new Gson().toJson(managedModel); // {id : 0, happy : false}

// We'll get the samething for this code
Model anotherManagedModel = realm.where(Model.class).equalTo("id",5).findFirst();
new Gson().toJson(anotherManagedModel); // {id : 0, happy : false}
```

We'll be surprised. We're seeing `nulls` everywhere!.

### Why?

*Gson* fails serializing a `RealmObject` only if it's a *managed* one. Which means that there's currently an opened `Realm` instance making sure this `RealmObject` is reflecting what is currently held in the persistence layer (the `Realm` database).

The reason why this is happening is due to the conflicting nature of how both *Gson* and *Realm* work. Quoting [Zhuinden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce) on why *Gson* sees `null` everywhere:

> ... that's because GSON tries to read the fields of the
> Realm object via reflection, but to obtain the values, you need to use
> accessor methods - which are automatically applied to all field access
> in the code via the Realm-transformer, but reflection still sees nulls
> everywhere...

[Christian Melchior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389357/christian-melchior) proposes a [workaround](https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/ddac8efd018123a1e53a) to this conflict by writing a custom `JsonSerializers` to every created `Model`. This is the workaround you have used, but **I would NOT recommend it**. As you have realized, it requires **writing a lot of code** which is **error prone** and the worst of all, **kills what `Gson` is about** (which is making our life less painful).

### Recommended solutions

If we can somehow make sure the `realmObject` we pass to Gson is not a `managed` one, we'll avoid this conflict.

#### Solution 1

Get a copy in memory of the managed RealmObject and pass it to *Gson*

```
new Gson().toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(managedModel));
```

#### Solution 2

(Wrapping the 1st solution). If the 1st solution is too verbose for you, make your models look like this one:

```
public class Model extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
    boolean happy;
    
    // Some methods ...

    public Model toUnmanaged() {
        return isManaged() ? getRealm().copyFromRealm(this) : this;
    }
}
```

And then, you can do something like this:

```
// always convert toUnmanaged when serializing
new Gson().toJson(model.toUnmanaged());
```

#### Solution 3

This one is **NOT very practical** but is worth mentioning. You can go with deep-cloning your models (taken from [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1127#issuecomment-273511736)).

1 - Create a generic interface CloneableRealmObject:

```
interface CloneableRealmObject<T> {
    T cloneRealmObject();
}
```

2 - Make your realmObjetcs implement the above interface like so:

```
public class Model extends RealmObject implements CloneableRealmObject<Model> {
    @PrimaryKey
    long id;

    public Model() {
        // Empty constructor required by Realm.
    }

    @Override
    public Model cloneRealmObject() {
        Model clone = new Model();
        clone.id = this.id;
        return clone;
    }
}
```

3 - Clone the object before passing to your Retrofit calls.

```
new Gson().toJson(model.cloneRealmObject());
```

## In a recent post

I gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42419154/3503855) explaining why we're getting this weird serialized output when using `managed` `realmObjects`. I recommend you to take a look at it.

## Bonus

You might also want to check [RealmFieldNamesHelper](https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper), a library made by [Christian Melchior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389357/christian-melchior) "to make Realm queries more type safe".

Comment: Retrofit doesn't use Gson by default. You have to explicitly set the data converter.

Comment: Because the minimal documentation just gives that as the copy-paste version of how to use Retrofit. Some people use it with Jackson

Comment: @cricket_007 Does jackson overcome these realm limitations? I've never used it before so I don't know it's limits.

Comment: Haven't used Realm yet, so dunno

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the similar issue. This is because your request format is wrong. In my case, I am trying to send a Realm object by getting it from local SQLite DB instead of Java object. Retrofit converts only Java object to JSON but not Realm object. Please make sure you are sending a right JSON as a request when using Retrofit.

Then I replaced this:

```
List<MyRealmModel> objectsToSync = mRealm.where(MyRealmModel.class).findAll();
```

To:

```
List<MyRealmModel> objectsToSend = mRealm.copyFromRealm(objectsToSync);
```