# Using Realm with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, realm, realm-java

I have `json` with field `_id`

```
 String json = "{ _id : 1, name : 'Alex', role: 'admin' }"
```

In my Realm model I use `@SerializedName` attribute:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("_id")  
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String comment;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

}
```

If try save the json:

`realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(User.class, json)`

field `_id` can't parsed and in database created record with id = 0

In docs using `@SerializedName` attribute

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            }).create();


User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);
```

In this case `json = "{ _id : 1, role: 'user' }"` just remove user `name` from database, because default value for String is null.

So, probably I incorrectly using the attribute. How to consider the attribute when dealing with the methods of conservation of json (`createOrUpdateObjectFromJson`, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need a hybrid solution in order to make this work. The reason is that `@SerializedName` is a GSON annotation and not one that Realm knows about. So this means you have two choices as you already discovered:

1) Use GSON, which means the end result is an object with `null` as the default for `name`.

2) Use `createOrUpdateObjectFromJson` which means that `_id` will be ignored because Realm's JSON parser require a 1:1 mapping.

As neither solution will work correctly you can modify them in the following way:

1) With GSON, instead of doing `copyToRealmOrUpdate` you can manually search for the object and update the role:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", user.getId()).findFirst().setRole(user.getRole());
realm.commitTransaction();
```

2) Using just the pure JSON you can modify to match the expected format:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
obj.put("id", obj.getString("_id"));
obj.remove("_id");
```

Realm has an issue tracking the request for custom mappings, but it has a low priority as that feature is usually better covered by frameworks such as GSON, Jacokson, etc. : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1470

Comment: thanks Christian. IMHO priority must be changed to normal :)

Answer (score 15):

Why writing all these custom serializers when you can make *Gson* and
*Realm* work together with just **ONE LINE OF CODE**?

**IMO**, setting an exclusive strategy to every model we want to serialize is not the best approach. As you have realized, this approach **requires writing a lot of boiler-plate code** which is **error prone** and the worst of all, **kills what *Gson* is about** (which is making our lives less painful).

And since we're working-around incompatibilities, why don't you just make sure to pass an unmanged *RealmObject* to your *Gson* serializer?

## Simplest solution ever (IMO)

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044320/3503855). Get a copy in memory of the managed *RealmObject* and pass it to *Gson*

```
new Gson().toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(managedModel));
```

And that's it! No more code to write!

Other good solutions and explanations are [posted here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044320/3503855)