# Retrofit 2 @Streaming freeze app

Tags: android, service, retrofit2, intentservice

I have an `IntentService` which represents one task in the download queue. I receive the data to download from an `Intent` in `onHandleIntent(Intent)` method. 
I am using retrofit 2 for download. In my app you have larger media files. For this reason, I want to use `@Streaming` annotation. When I do, the app freeze till the download is finished. I tried to wrap the code in a `Thread` but it did not help. When I don't use `@Streaming` than I can browse the app while the download is in progress. This however uses a lot of memory in because of the large `ResponseBody`.

```
@Streaming
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> downloadMediaFile(@Url String directDownload);
```

Service:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(intent != null && intent.hasExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_MEDIA)){
        final Media media = intent.getParcelableExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_MEDIA);

        FeedService feedService = ApiServices.get().getFeedService();
        String url = media.getDirectDownload();
        Call<ResponseBody> call = feedService.downloadMediaFile(url);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                File resultFile = response.isSuccessful() ? writeResponse(response.body(), media) : null;
                LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, resultFile != null ? "Download successful" : "Download unsuccessful");

                if(resultFile != null){
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MediaDownloadComplete(media, resultFile));
                } else {
                    onFailure(call, new NullPointerException("No result file received"));
                }

                if(DownloadManager.get() != null){
                    DownloadManager.get().nextInQueue();
                }

                media.setInProgress(false);
                stopSelf();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                media.setInProgress(false);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`DownloadManager` is a `Service` which handles the download queue.

Comment: How did you try to wrap in a thread? I've tested this with @Streaming and it worked: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-download-files-from-server

Comment: I have wrapped this in a AsyncTask following [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-download-files-from-server) guide. I have managed to get it working by using synchronous call instead inside the `doInBackground` method. I will post the answer later.

Comment: I too faced similar issue checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55195053/2462531 how I fixed.