# Realm and Retrofit2: sending auto-managed objects

Tags: android, gson, realm, retrofit2

When using Realm and Retrofit2 for sending auto-managed RealmObjects to our server, Retrofit2 (using Gson) only sends the ints in the RealmObject. It completely ignores the Strings and other fields, and does not put these in the json. No errors are logged.

If I however, **disconnect the RealmObject** from Realm:

```
realm.copyFromRealm(myRealmObject)
```

then it does send all fields. What could be the problem? Is there a proper solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Before we dive in

In one of my posts here on Stackoverflow, I have explained what's happening when using Gson and Realm together (Retrofit is just using Gson  as a data converter, so it's Gson that's failing not Retrofit). The link is posted down below.

## Let's dive in

> ... only sends the ints in the RealmObject

Nope! Not just `ints`...

If you look closely, you'll notice that even your `ints` are set to 0 (which is the `null` value for an `int`). The same thing would happen with a `boolean`, you would get `false` in the serialized output.

In fact, all your `RealmObject` attributes are set to `null` when this same `realmObject` is  **managed**. When you try to read/write an attribute (from a managed `realmObject`), Realm will read/write its value from/to the persistence layer (using [proxies](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging)) so you're sure you're getting/setting the right value of this `realmObject` (not just getting an old value from the memory).

That being said, I can now explain why Gson is only serializing `ints`.

- When your attribute is an `object`, its value will be equal to `null` (a reference pointing to nowhere) and Gson won't bother serializing it (you won't see it in the output).
- When your attribute is a scaler type (`char`, `int`, `boolean`, `float` ...) its value will be equal to whatever corresponds to a `null` (every bit in the scalar is 0) and Gson will serialize it cause it's considered to be a valid value. This explains "why only your `ints` are serialized".

> If I however, disconnect the RealmObject from Realm ... then it does
> send all fields.

When your `realmObject` is **unmanaged** it'll act a normal java object (no proxies are used to maintain the coherence between the object in memory and the persisted one) and of course Gson will have no trouble serializing it.

> Is there a proper solution?

There are workarounds. In the post I mentioned earlier, I tried to gather some recommended ones (IMO) to deal this incompatibility. Here's the link: ["Android: Realm + Retrofit 2 + GSON"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044320/3503855).

Comment: Thanks @AnixPasBesoin

Comment: more info here: https://medium.com/@ffvanderlaan/realm-auto-updated-objects-what-you-need-to-know-b2d769d12d76#.yvpvsft1d

Answer (score 0):

Your code `realm.copyFromRealm(myRealmObject)` change a `RealmObject`  to a normal object (POJO), said by document **Makes an unmanaged in-memory copy of an already persisted RealmObject** (although you can define `depth` parameter.)

With `Retrofit2`, now only support normal object, I think your codes are absolutely correct, but GSON reads field values for serialization, and managed Realm proxies have all `null` fields (read [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging)).

Change `RealmObject` to normal Java object using `realm.copyFromRealm()` and send it to server.

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it saved my day. `realm.copyFromRealm()` did the trick