# Serialization of Custom Class Using GSON

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson

I list of objects of a custom class which i am trying to serialize using json but the values once serialized are 0 and not the actual values that are stored in the list.

MyCustom Class

```
public class CustomClass extends RealmObject {

@Expose()
@SerializedName("startID")
private int startMessageID;

@Expose()
@SerializedName("endID")
private int endMessageID;

@Expose(serialize = false)
private boolean syncing = false;

}
```

The following is what i use to serialize the list.

```
 GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<CustomClass >>() {
    }.getType();

    Log.i("Json", gson.toJson(syncModelList, listType));
```

The above code produces an output of

```
[{"endID":0,"startID":0},{"endID":0,"startID":0}]
```

The structure is correct but my values are lost,i have checked the values before serialization and they are correct and exist.

Comment: Have a look at this, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230451/android-realm-retrofit-2-gson/42044320#42044320

Comment: @Snapper that worked thanks,if you write it as an answer i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Gson can't serialize a managed Realm object. You need to convert it to an unmanaged object first, like this:

```
new Gson().toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(managedModel));
```

Have a look at this answer for a full explanation [Android: Realm + Retrofit 2 + Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230451/android-realm-retrofit-2-gson/42044320#42044320)